# .NET 5.0 Web API project returning 404 when {domain}/swagger/index.html is requested after deployment

Tags: docker, .net-core, swagger-ui, .net-5, swashbuckle

I am new to .NET Core 5.0, currently working in a project where we have developed a multi-project Web API solution. For each Web API project, there is a startup.cs file, inside it we have the Swagger code like `UseSwagger(...)`, `UseSwaggerUI(....)`.

Now the issue is, Swagger is working fine in local (i.e., when I run the API on the local machine and request the URL http://localhost:5000/userService/swagger/index.html, it's showing up the API URLs etc). But when the API is deployed in AWS and a request is made to https://{domain}/userService/swagger/index.html, it returns 404.

Domain -: (provided by AWS)
Deployment is done through a Jenkins pipeline which internally calls the  Dockerfile (each API project has a Dockerfile) to build and publish the .NET Core project.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you setting ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to 'Development'? By default, Swagger is only available in development environments in projects generated from a template.

Comment: I have already removed the environment check 'if' block, we want swagger to be available in all environments, so this means the app.UseSwagger(...); app.UseSwaggerUI(...) codes are directly within configure method of startup.cs. Still nothing appears.

Comment: Are the 'real' API endpoints responding as they should?

Comment: Yes, I checked with postman tool. What I am thinking is whether there may be any path issue? Because the code in UseSwaggerUI () is like this -: UseSwaggerUI (c=> c.swaggerEndpoint('/userService/swagger/index.html) ;);. Also when I check the published files (using dotnet publish) , I don't see any index.html file generated in the bin/Release/net5.0/publish.... But it has swashbuckle DLL files

Comment: you don't have any kind of virtual directories there, right? you domain is just like `domain.com`? Without any parts like `domain.com/somepath`?

Comment: No we don't have any sort of virtual directory. As we have multiple API projects within a single solution, so to recognise the swagger url for a particular API project, I have modified the swagger Endpoint inside UseSwaggerUI () like this -: c.RoutePrefix= "userService/swagger" & then c.SwaggerEndpoint("/userService/swagger/v1/.."). Am I doing it wrong?? it works fine in local though.

Comment: @DibyoChatterjee It can be the issue, I believe it's better to show these parts of code in your question

Comment: I removed that '/userService/' part from swagger Endpoint,  now the Endpoint is '/swagger/v1/swagger.json', but no luck. Still the same issue, when I am requesting https://{domain}/swagger/index.html, its returning 404. Is there any other changes needed to be done in code ?? Or the issue is in loadbalancer url??